# arrayBuffer.slice() fails on android stock browser - any efficient alternatives?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm loading a ByteArray via a websocket that includes several chunks of jpeg image data along with x ,y ,width and height values.

I'm using a Uint8Array typed array to load it and arrayBuffer and DataView to read the data so I can draw it on the canvas at the relevant xy position. I use a slice() to grab the the bytes that belong to each jpeg image in a loop. Something like:

```
var arrayBuffer = array.buffer;
var jpegByteArray = arrayBuffer.slice(pointer, amountOfBytes + pointer);
```

This works fine on Chrome / Firefox and iOS 6+, but the **slice()** function **fails on Android Stock Browser** - any recommended efficient alternatives?

To confirmt this outside of my code I used this page http://www.javascripture.com/ArrayBuffer - Android stock browser still fails on slice() - I've tried ICS and JellyBean.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Stuck on the same thing. I have built a webupload which cuts the files into chunks and I also use the slice function for that. Not working on android though. Tried ponting slice on Array.prototype.slice with no avail, tried to read manually but I can not find any way to read a part from a file as a bytearry (and everything I read tells me it is evil to try that and I should use slice -.-).

Comment: I never found a solution to this, ended up targeting Android Chrome only (which isn't ideal - but suitable for us atm)